# Como se puede crear una aplicación exclusivamente para ciertos modelos de iphone?

Tags: xcode

Que tal, miren el problema es el siguiente, soy desarrollador de videojuegos para móviles, hay un desarrollo que se hizo para VR pero solo debe ser compatible con ciertos modelos de iphones, especificamente el 5, 5s, 6, 6s y se. El juego se desarrollo en Unity y se exporta para xcode, y ahi se compila (todo hasta aqui sin problemas) pero al subirlo a la tienda de apple dice "Tu archivo binario indica compatibilidad con la pantalla de retina de 4 pulgadas" lo mismo sucede con la de 3.5, y ipad. alguien tiene idea de como se puede solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿por que quieres limitar el uso en dispositivos?

Answer (score 1):

Desafortunadamente eso no se puede realizar en iOS, únicamente puedes restringir si el dispositivo es iPhone, iPad o ambos!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes editar el  [Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) para definir que el dispositivo pueda tener ciertas características, lo cual es descrito en este enlace:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257987/250260 (inglés)

pero esto **no es recomendable ya que corres el riesgo que tu aplicación sea rechazada**.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Lo que pregunta el OP es como se puede realizar el filtrado de ciertos dispositivos iPhone/iOS con ciertas características.

Answer (score 1):

Apple no permite la restricción de dispositivos ya que es parte de las ventajas de iOS. Imagina que pudiéramos restringir una app a solo ser utilizada para iPhone 6s... sería un despropósito.

Dicho esto, puedes hacer ciertas cosas para limitar al máximo la cantidad de dispositivos. 
Por un lado, configurar en la app que solo sea para `iPhone`, `iPad` o ambos. Después, puedes editar el `Info.plist` para obligar al dispositivo a tener ciertas características y de esta manera limitar un poco más el rango de dispositivos. Debes utilizar la key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` con las opciones que creas oportuno. Por ejemplo, si utilizas la opción `bluetooth-le` harás que solo pueda utilizarse en `iPhone 4S` y posterior y en `iPad 3` y posterior. Por otro lado, si utilizas la opción `camera-flash` lo restringirás a los `iPhone` y los `iPad Pro` de 9.7". Después, utilizando la opción `arm64` harás que solo sea `iPhone 5S` o posterior y `iPad Air` o posterior.

Como ves, hay muchas combinaciones y sería complicado conseguir únicamente los `iPhone 5` o posterior. Puedes consultar el listado de opciones [aquí](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, el problema realmente por el que estoy buscando restringirlo es que debido al tamaño de algunos dispositivos no son compatibles con los headset de VR (carboard por ejemplo) pero con esto que me comentas espero poder solucionarlo. Te agradezco mucho

Comment: Si es por eso no te preocupes, ponlo claramente en la descripción del iTunes Store y listo.